# std bind for overloaded template function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, boost

I'm new to C++, especially templates. I'm trying to use bind to an overloaded template function - the actual function is serial_port::set_option. For now i have reached the following form:

```
auto f = std::bind(static_cast<boost::system::error_code(serial_port::*)
(const SettableSerialPortOption&,boost::system::error_code&)>
(&serial_port::set_option),sp_ptr,_1,ec);
```

with sp_ptr defined as:

```
std::shared_ptr<serial_port> sp_ptr;
```

the overloaded method definition is:

```
template<
    typename SettableSerialPortOption>
boost::system::error_code set_option(
    const SettableSerialPortOption & option,
    boost::system::error_code & ec);
```

My intention is to get a call like:

```
f(boost::asio::serial_port::baud_rate(9600));
```

to work. I have no idea where to define the name `SettableSerialPortOption`. Can you provide some help on this?

Comment: Won't `std::bin(static_cast<...>(...), sp_ptr.get(), ...)` work?

Comment: or even `std::bin(static_cast<...>(...), *sp_ptr.get(), ...)`

Comment: I guess `SettableSerialPortOption` is not a concrete type ? for that you'd need a generic lambda (c++14), or a custom functor

Comment: @YSC Well the problem is somehow integrating the template SettableSerialPortOption in the call to std::bind or somewhere before, the template should be visible to f's declaration.

Comment: @Kalibr you can't *bind* to a function template, you can bind to a concrete instantiation of a function template, thus refer to my above proposals

Comment: Please self-answer instead of editing the answer into your question.  Also, consider using `[local_ptr,&ec] (auto&& a){local_ptr->set_option(decltype(a)a,ec);}` (perfect forwarding)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: I was able to do it with:

```
auto &local_ptr = sp_ptr;
auto f = [local_ptr,&ec] (auto&& a){local_ptr>set_option(decltype(a)a,ec);};
f(baud_rate);
```

Thanks to Piotr Skotnicki for the solution.
(perfect forwarding) Thanks to Yakk, I need to read about this, it's getting quite technical for me, but for other users and future reference apparently this is the way to go.